# Starting Eclipse as AUT in RCPTT results in an empty Eclipse window

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcptt

**What I have:** I want to create an application under test (AUT) in the RCPTT IDE. I choose an existing and functioning Eclipse folder on my desktop as the AUT but when I start it the result is this: [image], while my advanced configuration looks like this: [image]

Any thoughts how to get this to start right?

Comment: Had you added the snapshot of your Workbench and Workspace as a context to your RCPTT project?

Comment: Any tutorials on how I do that?

Comment: I used these to ramp-up: https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/getstarted/